# Application component is not getting launched - Angular2

Tags: angular

A breif explaination here about my application:-

Workbook is the parent component which has dropdown. Onchange event of the dropdown would trigger the PivotGrid component which is a child component of Workbook component, to load and bind the PivotGrid. After the PivotGrid grid is bound/loaded, it should load the selector for the PivotGrid. this selector is placed in a child component called slideout under this PivotGrid.

Basically whenever the dropdown is getting changed, it should load the appropriate PivotGrid and its selector components respectively.

I have added all these components and its references, but when I try to execute the application, the application is not loading in the browser. I am getting the message "**Workbook Loaded here...**" but the dropdown in the workbook component is not visible/loaded. Even If there is any errors/excecptions, atleast it should show in the browser console, but currently it is not showing.
any ideas why I am getting this error?

My application code can be downloaded from [url](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/PivotGridSample)

Comment: Can you show us the errors ?

Comment: That's the problem, I am not getting any errors either during compilation or even during runtime. Just I am getting this html content  "Workbook Loaded here...", But it is not loading any angular2 component. No error message is displayed on the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a great number of problems in your code, but I have managed to get the component to display using the code provided in your [Github](https://github.com/snkrishnan1/PivotGridSample). To do this, I've had to make a few changes:

1. In `Workbook.ts`, `SlideOut.ts` and `app.ts`, changed `import { SessionService } from './SessionService';` to `import { SessionService } from './SessionService.ts';` (i.e. included `.ts`).
2. Moved your `@NgModule` class from the bottom of `Workbook.ts` into `app.ts`.
3. Added `import { Workbook } from './Workbook.ts';` to the top of `app.ts`.

As I've said, you have more issues, but this gets you to the point where the `Workbook` component loads into the browser.